# SkipFolderList argument in Web-Deploy skips more than just the folder

Tags: powershell, iis, webdeploy

We use WebDeploy to deploy our .Net project. When we would like to deploy the package, there is a certain folder in which we don't want to override the files. I have read in the [WebDeploy Powershell Cmdlets documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/publish/using-web-deploy/web-deploy-powershell-cmdlets) that the 
`SkipFolderList` argument does just that: it specifies which folders shouldn't be overwritten. However, when we execute the following cmdlet, everything gets skipped, not just the specified folder.

```
$folderList = @('\\Scripts\Custom\Resources')
Restore-WDPackage $WebApp.Path -skipFolderList $folderList -parameters @{"IIS Web Application Name" = $WebsiteName+"\"+$WebApp.Name}
```

Are we using the argument wrong? Should the address be specified in a different way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found you use the wrong powershell folder parameter "\Scripts\Custom\Resources", if you use this parameter, it will show the  "The regular expression '\Scripts\Custom\Resources' is invalid." error.

I guess this is the reason why you find your depoy command is useless.

I suggest you could try to use below command, then it will work well.

```
$folderList = @('\\Scripts\\Custom\\Resources')
```

Result:

[image]

IIS folder: It doesn't add anything.

[image]